# Loop through an array with pointers?

Tags: c

I am trying to learn pointers which is a real PITA when you don't quite fully understand it.

I am trying to print all the elements in the array but only the first element is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count(const int* numbers, int size)
{
    for(; numbers < size; numbers++)
    {
        printf("%d", *numbers);
    }
}

int main(void)
{

    int numbers[] = {3, 4, 6, 3, 46};

    int result = count(numbers, 5);

    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

The loop in the **count** function does not seem to work properly since it is only looping through one time but I can't understand why.

Comment: No return value in count function ?

Comment: My bad. I haven't really got there yet. I am focusing on getting the loop to work first.

Comment: Stupid question (just curious): are you running a non x86 architecture?

Comment: I am running Win 7 x64, why is that in your interest? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison `numbers < size` is wrong.

You have 3 options:

1. Have a separate index variable:

   ```
   int count;
   for(count = 0; count < size; count++)
   {
       printf("%d", numbers[count]);
   }
   ```
2. Have a separate "cursor" pointer:

   ```
   const int * const end = numbers + size;
   for(; numbers < end; numbers++)
   {
       printf("%d", *numbers);
   }
   ```
3. Decrement `size`:

   ```
   for(; size != 0; size--, numbers++)
   {
       printf("%d", *numbers);
   }
   ```

Comment: Well put. I'd make it `int * const end = orig + size;` to make sure it's not accidentally modified, too.

Answer (score 2):

Because numbers is a pointer, it contains an address. `size` is an `int` and equals `5`. The address is not 5, nor is it even near 5.

You might save the start address and calculate the offset:

```
int count(const int* numbers, int size)
{
  const int* start = numbers;
  for(; (int)(numbers - start) < size; numbers++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", *numbers);
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not really understand how `const int* start = numbers;` differs from `numbers`, since they are equal? :S

Can I not type `for(*numbers < size; numbers++)`? Oh, no I can't, since then I am comparing size with the values in the array, not the index...

Comment: `numbers` is the address of your array cell, `*numbers` the value in the cell pointed to. `size` is apparently the number of cells you have in your array, so you need to know how many cells you've printed. `start` differs from `number` since your `for` loop does `numbers++` after each iteration.

Comment: It's the same as saying "From 121 Smith Road, tell me the names of people living in the 5 next houses". You won't check the address of the house against 5, you will remember having started at 121, so upon arriving at 127 you will do the calculation in your head (127-121 = 6) and realise you've done the 5 asked for so you're finished

Comment: Yes, on ideone. The only thing misssing is the return in `count()` but since OP sends `size` to that method, I don't know what he wants returned. I only addressed the condition problem.

Answer (score 2):

the `count()` function should be

```
int count(const int* numbers, int size)
{
    for(; size > 0; numbers++, size--)
    {
        printf("%d", *numbers);
    }
}
```